# Pug/Jade template engine: html beautifier?

Tags: node.js, pug, express

I'm using jade/pug template engine with ExpressJS on Node.js. It outputs a html with single line. No indentation at all. I couldn't find any beautifier option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExpressJS: how to output pretty html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276892/expressjs-how-to-output-pretty-html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There used to be a {pretty: true} option but it was removed because it messed up with whitespaces.

Refs:

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/#issue/91
https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/closed/#issue/89

Answer (score 6):

In app.js, pass the `pretty` option to the Jade compiler.

```
app.set('view options', { pretty: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are compileing from console, then you can use this :

```
jade views/ --out html --pretty layout.jade
```

it will generate beutyfied code in html folder.