# How can I get Express to output nicely formatted HTML?

Tags: node.js, express, pug, pretty-print

When using Express for Node.js, I noticed that it outputs the HTML code without any newline characters or tabs. Though it may be more efficient to download, it's not very readable during development.

How can I get Express to output nicely formatted HTML?

Answer (score 317, accepted):

In your main `app.js` or what is in it's place:

**Express 4.x**

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.locals.pretty = true;
}
```

**Express 3.x**

```
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
  app.locals.pretty = true;
});
```

**Express 2.x**

```
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
  app.set('view options', { pretty: true });
});
```

I put the pretty print in `development` because you'll want more efficiency with the 'ugly' in `production`. Make sure to set environment variable `NODE_ENV=production` when you're deploying in production. This can be done with an `sh` script you use in the 'script' field of `package.json` and executed to start.

Express 3 [changed](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) this because:

> The "view options" setting is no longer necessary, app.locals are the local variables merged with res.render()'s, so [app.locals.pretty = true is the same as passing res.render(view, { pretty: true }).

Comment: Please change the accepted answer to this as it's the right answer to date.

Comment: This worked, but I had to install a bunch of extra dependencies, namely `promise`, `uglify-js`, `css` and `lexical-scope` before it would run again (it would build, but crash on first request). I only added that one line.

Comment: How to do that in Express 4.x ?

Comment: @AntonioSalvati try `app.locals.pretty = true`

Comment: This is an awesome answer, exactly what I was looking for. It's refreshing to see how this is done for different versions of Express. I've searched for other issues and found answers that didn't mention what version of Express it was for.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @gustavohenke there's a link in my answer

Comment: Yes, I see this... but it's not available in the Express 4 docs. At least I tried to google "pretty site:expressjs.com" to no avail

Comment: Great answer. But I see no reason to only pretty print in development mode. HTML is very small, especially for a Single Page App like angular. Plus there is no looping going on like in javascript, unless you put JS directly in your code (which you shouldn't unless absolutely necessary for setting a global JS var from the server, etc). Either way I always want to format my HTML so if there is some problem in production its apparent. Javascript however I would only pretty print for development.

Answer (score 51):

To "pretty-format" html output in Jade/Express:

```
app.set('view options', { pretty: true });
```

Comment: **Great solution!** I wish it would match indent levels between layout/page too.

Comment: Outdated. Express 3 works a little different, see post written by EhevuTov.

Answer (score 7):

There is a "pretty" option in Jade itself:

```
var jade = require("jade");

var jade_string = [
    "!!! 5",
    "html",
    "    body",
    "        #foo  I am a foo div!"
].join("\n");

var fn = jade.compile(jade_string, { pretty: true });
console.log( fn() );
```

...gets you this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="foo">I am a foo div!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I doesn't seem to be very sophisticated but for what I'm after -- the
ability to actually debug the HTML my views produce -- it's just fine.

Comment: If debugging HTML is all you're after you could always just 'inspect' the HTML using the Webkit or Firebug inspector. That always generates a perfectly formatted DOM tree.

Comment: @Roshambo true, but navigating through the tree is time consuming, when u can just scan the source quicker (sometimes)

Answer (score 7):

In express 4.x, add this to your app.js:

```
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.locals.pretty = true;
}
```

Comment: Worked here - thanks! In my case I didn't have the 'env' var set.  You can add it to the main .js file with this one line : *process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';*

Comment: Why are you giving this answer if other answers already are giving this solution?

Comment: I was the first to give this answer, the other answer was updated afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the console to compile, then you can use something like this:

```
$ jade views/ --out html --pretty
```

Answer (score 1):

In express 4.x, add this to your app.js:

```
app.locals.pretty = app.get('env') === 'development';
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need nicely formatted html? Even if you try to output something that looks nice in one editor, it can look weird in another. Granted, I don't know what you need the html for, but I'd try using the chrome development tools or firebug for Firefox. Those tools give you a good view of the DOM instead of the html.

If you really-really need nicely formatted html then try using EJS instead of jade. That would mean you'd have to format the html yourself though.

Comment: I like ejs better now that I've worked with it for a while. I guess I'm just very particular about some things.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)

take for example this jade file:

**foo.jade**

```
h1 MyTitle

p
  a(class='button', href='/users/') show users

table
  thead
    tr
      th Name
      th Email
  tbody
    - var items = [{name:'Foo',email:'foo@bar'}, {name:'Bar',email:'bar@bar'}]
    - each item in items
      tr
        td= item.name
        td= item.email
```

now you can process it with **node testjade.js foo.jade > output.html**:

**testjade.js**

```
var jade = require('jade');
var jadeFile = process.argv[2];
jade.renderFile(__dirname + '/' + jadeFile, options, function(err, html){
    console.log(html);
});
```

will give you s.th. like:

**output.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><head><title>My Title</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"/><script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script></head><body><div id="main"><div ><h1>MyTitle</h1><p><a href="/users/" class="button">show users</a></p><table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Foo</td><td>foo@bar</td></tr><tr><td>Bar</td><td>bar@bar</td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></body></html
```

then running it through tidy with **tidy -m output.html** will result in:

**output.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content=
"HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />
<title>My Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css" type=
"text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div>
<h1>MyTitle</h1>
<p><a href="/users/" class="button">show users</a></p>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Foo</td>
<td>foo@bar</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Bar</td>
<td>bar@bar</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

building off of oliver's suggestion, heres a quick and dirty way to view beautified html

1) download [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#source)

2) add this to your .bashrc

```
function tidyme() {
curl $1 | tidy -indent -quiet -output tidy.html ; open -a 'google chrome' tidy.html
}
```

3) run

```
$ tidyme localhost:3000/path
```

the open command only works on macs. hope that helps!

Comment: didn't know about the indent option...nice! I was using vim's built in formater.