# Node.js JADE linebreaks in source?

Tags: node.js, pug

I wonder, why i don't see any linebreaks in my sourcecode if i parse my jade template. It looks like this:

```
!!! 5
html
head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/css.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/table_jui.css')

    script(type="text/javascript", src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="/javascripts/jquery.jwNotify.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="/javascripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js")
    script(type="text/javascript", src="/javascripts/js.js")

body!= body
```

Now my sourcecode looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Express v2</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/css.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/table_jui.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.jwNotify.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/js.js"></script></head><body></body></html>
```

Would be fine to see line breaks in sourcecode to debug or not? Anyone has an ideo, how i can manage this? Thx for info!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sometimes, you want to see pretty html output. To un-uglify your Jade output, pass the `pretty` option to the compiler in your app.js:

```
app.set('view options', { pretty: true });
```

Comment: With Express v3.x, remember that you need this instead: app.locals.pretty = true;

Comment: you may also use the --pretty switch if calling jade from the shell

Answer (score 7):

Because Jade doesn't compile any line breaks into your html source by default.

It's just sending unneccesary bytes to the client slowing download speed and increasing bandwidth consumption.

Similar Question: [Express and pretty HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276892/expressjs-how-to-output-pretty-html/5297798#5297798)

Comment: Thx, I think im understanding now :)