# Turn on line breaks in Jade source?

Tags: debugging, node.js, express, pug

Is there a way to turn on line breaks? It would be useful when debugging.

I know this topic ( [Node.js JADE linebreaks in source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504624/node-js-jade-linebreaks-in-source) ) says no due to performance, but on your local machine when developing, it should't be a problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit of searching I found the solution. Add this to your Express configuration, and it will make Jade tidy up the output:

**Express 3.x CoffeeScript**

```
app.configure "development", ->
  app.use express.errorHandler()
  app.locals.pretty = true
```

**Express 3.x Javascript**

```
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
  app.locals.pretty = true;
});
```

**Express 2.x CoffeeScript**

```
app.configure "development", ->
  app.use express.errorHandler()
  app.set "view options",
    pretty: true
```

**Express 2.x Javascript**

```
app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
  app.set('view options', { pretty: true });
});
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for saving me some time. It's a bit hard to debug all as one line :)

Comment: Hello @Alfred, do we have similar solution for debugging `pug` file ? I am not finding anything on how to debug pug file.

Comment: Sorry @S.K I've not used pug files I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it through a beautifier for debugging

here's one written for node https://github.com/maxogden/commonjs-html-prettyprinter