# Why won't Jade format its output correctly in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using Jade in Express.js and I noticed that the html output is all in one line. On the Jade website ( http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/jade-syntax.html ) it says that formatted output is standard and that the options are ScamlOptions.nl and ScamlOptions.indent, but I can't find those options anywhere to see if they are set incorrectly. Does anyone know where I can find those options or is there another way to force clean formatting?

Thanks!

This thread didn't help:
[How to output pretty html in Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276892/expressjs-how-to-output-pretty-html)

Comment: Scalate is Scala implementation of jade. JavaScript jade implementation, which are utilized by express, placed in the project repo on the github https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme

Comment: See this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276892/expressjs-how-to-output-pretty-html

Comment: Why didn't the two stackoverflow links specified help?  How are you formatting your Express view options?

Answer (score 9):

In Express 3, the api has changed for (at least) this view option.

I set `app.locals.pretty` and it seems to be working just fine. I call it within my `app.js` (or `server.js`) right after I set the view engine in `app.configure()`

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  app.locals.pretty = true;
  next();
});
```

Comment: For express 3.x this is correct. You can place it in your app.js - if you've used the bare bones express scaffold place `app.locals.pretty = true;` under the `// all environments` section.

Answer (score 7):

1. **Scalate != Jade**

Also, Jade is not designed to create human-readable output. All the indention and new lines are just wasting space and are not important for any browser to process you HTML. But you could try:

1. Try: `app.set('view options', { pretty: true });`
2. Use Firebug or Chrome Inspector to view your HTML ;-)
3. Use any HTML cleanup tool.

Comment: This was with express 2 (or even express 1), they changed the API of express with the release of version 3. @AmericanYak