# jade to html with new line

Tags: pug

in jade, I use:

```
each item in items
  li
    a(href='http://www.#{item.href}/') #{item.name}
```

the html output is ok, but in only one big line.
how I can get a newline between every list element ? like

```
<li><a ...</a></li>
<li><a ...</a></li>
<li><a ...</a></li>
```

Comment: more info in [ExpressJS: how to output pretty html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276892/expressjs-how-to-output-pretty-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable jade's pretty mode.
Pass `{pretty: true}` in the options