# Can I configure Jade to generate readable well-indentated HTML code rather than single-line stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am exploring Node, Express and Jade and have found it generating single-line concatenated HTML code line. Needless to say this is quite an inconvenience when the task is to explore how the things work and debug my first apps. Can it be configured to generate code intended for a human to read? I mean with tags starting on new lines and tags hierarchy outlined with reasonable indentation?

Comment: `-P, --pretty : compile pretty html output`

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276892/expressjs-how-to-output-pretty-html

Comment: That question-answer helped, @elclanrs, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jade API, you can use `jade.compile(template, { pretty: true })(model)`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea where to put this yet :-] So I am going with `App.locals.pretty = true;` for now... Thank you for your answer anyway.