# Yesod: how to output pretty html

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

How do i print nice formatted html?

I want something like `app.locals.pretty = true`.
[ExpressJS: how to output pretty html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276892/expressjs-how-to-output-pretty-html)

Answer (score 1):

According to [`Text.Hamlet.Html`'s definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shakespeare-2.0.5/docs/Text-Hamlet.html#t:Html), Hamlet uses `blaze-markup` for its output. `blaze-markup`, in turn, has a renderer backend with the promising name [`Text.Blaze.Renderer.Pretty`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-markup-0.7.0.2/docs/Text-Blaze-Renderer-Pretty.html).

So I think what should work is if you run your Hamlet templates to get the final `Html`, and then render it yourself by calling `Text.Blaze.Renderer.Pretty.renderMarkup`.