# Render formatted (unminified) HTML in React (SSR with Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, server-side-rendering, html-rendering, next.js

How can I render formatted (unminified) HTML in React (SSR with Next.js)?

Expected output:

```
<div>
   <div>
       <input type="text" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Now receiving:

```
<div><div><input type="text"/></div></div>
```

TY!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to format the output before actually returning to browser. So as for nextjs, first switch to the custom server [nexjs custom server and routing](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-server-and-routing) and walkthrough [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276892/how-to-output-pretty-html-in-express) answer for pretty printing html. Using nextjs or react SSR, this may not be possible as a built-in configurable option.

Comment: Thank you! That was what I needed!

Comment: @NikolaKnežević glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml). It allows you to pass in a string that you want rendered as raw HTML.

```
function createMarkup() {
  return {__html: '<div><div><input type="text"/></div></div>'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not my question. I mean entire page is rendered minified (in 1 line).