# How to temporarily disable html compression in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Is there any way/options to change Next.js output so that it avoid compressing html source?

Comment: Adding `compress: false` to your next.config.js should turn off all compression — I don't see an option to turn it off per filetype, but if it's a temporary change that might work fine for you.

Comment: Doesn't work: that's for gzip compression

Comment: Oh, then by compression did you mean minification? I believe Next calls `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup` under the hood, which doesn't have an option like that, so your best bet would be to run something like tidy or some other formatter afterwards.

Comment: (Out of time to edit): I meant renderToString, not renderToStaticMarkup.

Comment: @LucaReghellin Would this solution work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45297699/1870780?

Comment: @Julio thnk you, it probably would do the trick but I hoped in something less involved. It's not a realy important issue to me, it was just for better testing, but I can do test in other ways. Thank you