# Why is view source unreadable?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, bundle, xss

I am trying to use view-source to find XSS vulnerability but when I view-source the HTML is unreadable.

[image: image of view-source]

On other websites, such as stackoverflow, when you view-source the code is organized and readable.

Ironically, this is my website and I don't know why this is happening. I believe it has to do with bundling. I am using React and Next.js if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Render formatted (unminified) HTML in React (SSR with Next.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44956379/render-formatted-unminified-html-in-react-ssr-with-next-js)? There is no built-in way to prettify the HTML response in Next.js. You'll need to resort to a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) and format/prettify the response yourself.

Comment: code minification is included in most react setups.  Check your webpack configuration; there's often a separate development build that skips minification for testing; or you can generate sourcemaps which make the minified code intelligible.  I'm not too familiar with next.js but https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7494 looks promising

Comment: Returning minified code from the web server is a good thing! You can always use the developer tools to view the parsed HTML tree in a pretty form if you really like.

Comment: Yes! To clarify, I was only suggesting disabling it temporarily for debugging, or (better) using a separate unminified dev build  -- as @Alejandro says, you definitely want to keep minifying your production code.